# Getting Firestore Sub-Collection reponse as Instance of 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project to get my sub-collection data from firestore. I have a separate file with gets the data from the main collection via Stream, Now I'm trying to get the sub-collection data, My sub-collection consists of one main collection and a lot of different documents inside of it, which I will need to have access later. On the main page, I'm using Streambuilder to get the data to the main page.
Here is the file in which I'm getting the main collection data:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:homeautomation/modelos/dadosusuario.dart';
import 'package:homeautomation/modelos/user.dart';

class DatabaseService {
//Colection reference
final String uid;
DatabaseService({this.uid});

final CollectionReference userdata = Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios');

Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get userData{
return userdata.document(uid).snapshots();
}
}
```

This is the main page:

```
return  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder : ((context, snapshot){
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
           return  Loading();
          }
          int cardamount = snapshot.data['btncount'];

          //var botao  = Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document('5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2').collection('buttons').document().get();
          //print(botao);

          List<bool> cardsValue = [snapshot.data['device1'], snapshot.data['device2'], snapshot.data['device3']];

          return Scaffold(
```

When I use this in my main page:

```
var botao  = Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document('5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2').collection('buttons').document().get();
print(botao);
```

The print result is:

```
Instance of 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>'
```

What would I need to add, so I can have access to the Data inside my sub-collection?
This is how my database looks:
[image: Image1]
Sub-collection:
[image: Imag2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the result as `Future<DocumentSnapshot>` because Firestore will take some time to process the query as its an `async call`.To get the result you'll have to use `await` keyword or you can use then.

As @Doug Stevenson pointed out, your query needs to be updated.
Here is the updated code.

```
var botao  = await Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document('5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2').collection('buttons').getDocuments();
print(botao);
```

I suggest you look into [Asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: Could you add this inside a Future, so I can accept the answer

Comment: That depends on how you want to use it, If you wanted to build some widget from this data, you can simply add it to `FutureBuilder` or if you wanted to store the value you can define a function and call it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @shaubham Thats exactly what I need, I would need the FutureBuilder, But how could I add the futurebuilder if I have StreamBuilder already?

Comment: You can add FutureBuilder in a StreamBuilder, nothing is stopping you from doing that. But you'll have to wait for your `StreamBuilder` to finish first and then your `FutureBuilder` will run.

Comment: If the data you are fetching in Future is not dependant on the data from `StreamBuilder` then you can fetch the data somewhere else and sync with the UI, or instead of future if you are okay with Stream, you can look into CombineLatestStream from rxdart.

Comment: I would have to add the FutureBuilder inside Builder from StreamBuilder

Comment: Yes, so in the builder of your `StreamBuilder` you can return a `FutureBuilder` and it will work totally fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214287/discussion-between-shubham-and-nilton-schumacher-f).

Answer (score 1):

In this statement, you're passing no arguments to document():

```
var botao = Firestore.instance
    .collection('dadosusuarios')
    .document('5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2')
    .collection('buttons')
    .document()
    .get();
```

This doesn't really make sense for accessing data.  If you want to query a subcollection, you should instead call get() on the subcollection reference:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('dadosusuarios')
    .document('5j5UF0lFovW8g5QSXXymWYsz0QB2')
    .collection('buttons')
    .get();
```

That will give you a Future that you can use to iterate over all the documents.

Comment: How can I access the documents inside of it than?

Comment: Deal with the returned Future in the same way that you would deal with any Future.  Or use a stream if that's easier for you.  The main point is that your code isn't actually querying anything as you have it now.